# What is the command for not modularly congruent?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

The symbol for modularly congruent is ≡, which can be produced with `\equiv`.

For instance,

`18 ≡ 0 (mod 9)`

What is the symbol for not modularly congruent, and how do I represent it in TeX?

I have perused some references (including [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829051032/http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html)) and have not found it.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `\not\equiv`?

Comment: That looks right. Thank you! In general, does `\not` negate the following operation?

Comment: Yes, `\not` is defined zero width relation character in TeX so it will always be on top of the following character.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Negation of symbols in LaTeX is typically achieved prepending it with `\not`. For example

[image: Negating symbols]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$18 \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9) \not\equiv 2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$
\end{document}
```

For more elaborate, larger or lengthy symbols, you can use the [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel). In those instances `\not` may not provide a sufficiently-centred negation. The [`centernot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) also provides a centred `\not` for symbols with larger horizontal dimension.

The ≢ character is in Unicode as U+2262, and can be entered directly with `unicode-math`.  The command for it is `\nequiv` in many packages, including `unicode-math`, `pxfonts`, `txfonts`, `newpxmath`, `newtxmath`, `stix`, `stix2`, `mnsymbol` and `fdsymbol`.

Other symbol-lookup techniques are described in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: There's also the `centernot` package, which provides a `\centernot` command that measures its argument and centres the not correctly.

Comment: Also instead of writing `(\textrm{mod}\ 9)`, you can just write `\pmod{9}`.

Comment: @BlackSheep Thanks!  It was annoying me that `\mod` creates a wide space to the left (presumably meant for when you're not using the brackets) and I found myself having to use `\textrm{mod}` as a workaround.  So `\pmod` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

Here is an alternative, late answer using https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math, hence it requires `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`. The example uses various *modulo* macros of the package `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath,unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Here's to you, Donald and Leslie; 
\begin{align*}
    18 & \equiv 0 \bmod 9, \\
    18 &\nequiv 1  \mod 9, \\
    18 & \equiv 0 \pmod 9, \\
    18 &\nequiv 1  \pod 9.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]